# (lubuntu 14.04) Cannot close windows,minimise or maximise them

Tags: lxde

I am running lubuntu 14.04 on my desktop.I don't seem to have a close window ,minimize or maximize option in my program windows,neither in the top right corner nor in the left.when i go to Preferences>customize look and feel, there is no window borders option.Openbox seems to be already installed  and i dont' know what the problem is.Help please?

Comment: Perhaps window decorations are hidden? Press alt+spacebar and look for the Un/Decorate entry. That's a toggle. Also, post the output of `grep "titleLayout" ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`. Some Openbox settings are under Preferences > Openbox Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu->Preferences->Openbox Configuration Manager.  Choose Appearance and under Button Order make sure that NLIMC is entered.

Comment: No longer works in Ubuntu 20.04, as appears to be 100% true of all Ubuntu solutions on the SE network. NLIMC is already entered, still no way to move or close windows.